# How to make an empty int Array in processingJS?

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I am trying to create a lot of int values and trying to add them in an empty int array, but it's not working. I have added my code as is atm. It should work if you just plug it in. All the problematic parts are commented out.

All I am really trying to do is get it to use perfect colors that I want it to use. so a list of number has been created that represent the colors, and I need to add those colors into an array so i can initialize them with fill. So the question is how do I add all those values into an empty int array.

```
int rotationCount = 0;
int translateX ;
int translateY ;
int currentTime = 0;
int circlesOrLines ;
int timeLimit ;
int r;
int g;
int b;
//int[] values = new values [];
int maxValue = 226;
int minValue = 75;
int timeIndex = 0;

void setup () {
  size(500, 700);
  r = 226;
  g = 226;
  b = 75;

  smooth();
  background(0);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  frameRate (10);
  noStroke();
  fill(r, g, b, 30);
  translateX = width/2;
  translateY = height/2;
   timeLimit = 10000;
   circlesOrLines = 0;
   currentTime = millis();
   //generateColor ();

}

void draw () {
  background(80);
/*  
  timeIndex++;
  if (timeIndex >= values.length){
   timeIndex = 0; 
  }
  fill(values [timeIndex] , values [timeIndex + 1], values [timeIndex + 2], 30);

  */
  fill(r, g, b, 30);
  int passedTime = millis() - currentTime;
  println (" the passed time is " + passedTime);

  translate(translateX % width, translateY % height);


  translateX += 3 % width;
  translateY += 3 % height;

  rotationCount += (PI/2008);
  if (passedTime < timeLimit) {
    makeCircles ();
  }
  else {
    if (passedTime >=20000)
    {
      passedTime = 0;
      currentTime = millis();
    }
    makeLines ();

 }
}
void makeCircles () {

  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    rotate (rotationCount);
    ellipse(i+7, i % width, 100, height/2);
  }
}

void makeLines () {
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    rotate (rotationCount);
    rect(i+7, i % width, 100, height/2);
  }
}
/*
void generateColor () {

                       for (g=g; g>minValue; g--)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }
                       for (r=r; r>minValue; r--)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }
                       for (b=b; b<maxValue; b++)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }
                       for (g=g; g<maxValue; g++)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }
                       for (r=r; r<maxValue; r++)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }
                       for (b=b; b>minValue; b--)
                       {
                               values.push (r,g,b);
                       }


               }

*/
```

EDIT--------

THE JAVASCRIPT MODE :

[image]

Comment: None of this code should work in javascript at all. Are you sure you didn't mean Java?

Comment: umm I am under processing >> Javascript mode and it works fine

Comment: What mode? Are you talking about some IDE? I am sorry to inform you that you are writing plain Java and whatever is executing it is executing it as Java code. You should read up about what that mode means in the software that you are using.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you but then there is the inclusion of ProcessingJS (clearly a JavaScript framework) and that JavaScript `array.push()`. This is an odd question.

Comment: @Chandranshu I added a picture of what I mean. oh i can't use that? sorry I am really new to this, I honestly just looked it up online on how to addthing to array and tha came up, what else should I use

Comment: Ah, you are using the Processing visual programming language. It does allow you to write code in Java and then execute it on any HTML5 compatible browser.

Comment: yep yep :p how do i add stuff to array? lol

Comment: My answer below still remains valid though I need to check whether ArrayList is allowed by Processing.

Comment: yep, well before i added what you showed in the code, my code wasn't running at all, no wit's running, but not really working as it's supposed to. :(

Comment: Look at my updated answer and accept it :). If you are still facing problems, you should open a new question and someone will gladly reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted a working solution. There were a few errors in your code.

First, make sure you declare things that you use. You use `values` in your code but you crossed off the declaration. Javascript will allow calls to a null object, which is why you were calling `.push()` on your object and it was compiling but not working.

Second, keep the colors as `color` objects and use ArrayList to store them. It is easier to manage and will allow you to move between Java and Javascript versions of Processing with less trouble (the .push() method does not exist on an array in Java).

Lastly, when you were looking up the color with your call to `fill()` you were using timeIndex, which was not the same length as the array of colors, thus causing an exception. I've changed the lookup to use frameCount and the modulo of the ArrayList length to keep it oscillating through the colors but also prevent out of bounds errors.

The results looks very nice. Good job.

```
int rotationCount = 0;
int translateX ;
int translateY ;
int currentTime = 0;
int circlesOrLines ;
int timeLimit ;
int r;
int g;
int b;
ArrayList values;
int maxValue = 226;
int minValue = 75;
int timeIndex = 0;

void setup () {
    size(500, 700);
    r = 226;
    g = 226;
    b = 75;

    smooth();
    background(0);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    frameRate (10);
    noStroke();
    fill(r, g, b, 30);
    translateX = width/2;
    translateY = height/2;
    timeLimit = 10000;
    circlesOrLines = 0;
    currentTime = millis();


    values = new ArrayList();  
    generateColor ();

}

void draw () {
    background(80);

    fill( values.get( frameCount % values.size()));
    int passedTime = millis() - currentTime;

    translate(translateX % width, translateY % height);

    translateX += 3 % width;
    translateY += 3 % height;

    rotationCount += (PI/2008);
    if (passedTime < timeLimit) {
        makeCircles ();
    }
    else {
        if (passedTime >=20000)
        {
            passedTime = 0;
            currentTime = millis();
        }
        makeLines ();

    }
}
void makeCircles () {

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        rotate (rotationCount);
        ellipse(i+7, i % width, 100, height/2);
    }
}

void makeLines () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        rotate (rotationCount);
        rect(i+7, i % width, 100, height/2);
    }
}


void generateColor () 
{

    for (g=g; g>minValue; g--)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
    for (r=r; r>minValue; r--)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
    for (b=b; b<maxValue; b++)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
    for (g=g; g<maxValue; g++)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
    for (r=r; r<maxValue; r++)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
    for (b=b; b>minValue; b--)
    {
        values.add (color(r,g,b,30));
    }
}
```